# laptop not connecting via docking station

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, docking-station

I am using **Windows 7 Enterprise - Service Pack1**.  I was previously able to connect  my laptop to the LAN via  a docking station.

However, I can now connect to the LAN through the wire or connect through the wireless connection but no longer through a docking station (*I tried four separate docking stations*).  The network connection simply does not get picked up when I try the docking station (no response to ping as it times out).  Other users can connect via docking stations though.

I realize I am probably not providing enough information so kindly ask whatever other set of information will be useful to troubleshoot/fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What laptop / docking station are you using? Does the docking station have a separate power supply?

Comment: dell laptop - docking stations (best I can tell) have power input.  I used 4 separate docking stations which work with other laptops - just not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pilot error.  The service code sticker underneath the laptop had come off from its usual place and was affecting the connection to the docking station.  Thank you to anyone who commented.